# PHP Dropdown Dynamic Page Fill

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Is it possible to use pure PHP to select different `include_once 'template.php'"` from a dropdown menu?

In my head, it should be something like this:

```
<?php 
Connections to db
Include libs etc

Include header.php
?>

<Form to select which include template.php to display>

<?php

Include dynamictemplate.php <- from form dropdown on select.

Include footer
?>
```

Or am I better off using AJAX or JS for this?

Comment: You want to change part of the page *asynchronously* by calling different php files on `select` input change, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, instead of having many subsites to view table data that i currently have in seperate php files. F.ex now i have manage.php site with button links to users.php, category.php, products.php, series.php, set.php. i'd like to contain all those within manage.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AJAX can Do it very very efficiently. Whether you want to bring the whole page or certain parts, it can be handled in a pretty elegent way through AJAX. if there is any specific questions please get back. (It is my favorite topic, or better still, tag me)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in PHP.

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="manage.php">
<select name="select" onChange="document.form1.submit()">
<option selected>Select a Table</option>
<option value="product">Product</option>
<option value="series">Series</option>
<option value="set">set<option>
</select>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select']) { } else { include 
manage_product.php'; }

if (isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select'])
{
if ($_POST['select'] == 'product')
include 'manage_product.php';
if ($_POST['select'] == 'series')
include 'manage_series.php';
if ($_POST['select'] == 'set')
include 'manage_set.php';
}    else {
return;
}
?>
```

however this leaves a blank option field on the bottom of the dropdown list, do not know why, this option links to product.
And if you go back on the page it requires you to resend form info, which is slightly annoying. any tips on how to get rid of those?